# Get selected radio button value in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Here is my html file

```
<mat-radio-group  formControlName="select1" (click)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)" >
    <mat-radio-button formControlName="select1" value=post1 ngDefaultControl>
        {{post1}}
        per post
    </mat-radio-button>
          
    <br><br>
    <mat-radio-button formControlName="select1" value=story ngDefaultControl> 
          {{story}}
          per Story
    </mat-radio-button>
    <br><br>
            
    <mat-radio-button formControlName="select1" value=oth ngDefaultControl>
         {{oth}}
          both
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Here is my ts file

```
  onSearchChange(searchValue): void {
   alert(searchValue);
    this.Totalprice = parseFloat((parseFloat(this.price) * parseFloat(searchValue)).toFixed(2));
    this.TotalGst = parseFloat((((this.Totalprice) * 2) / 100).toFixed(2));
    this.finalamt = (this.Totalprice) + (this.TotalGst);

  }
```

I want a checked radio button value in onSearchChange method, please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `onSearchChange` in a `(change)` event on your radio buttons like this:

```
<mat-radio-group  formControlName="select1" >
    <mat-radio-button formControlName="select1" value=post1 ngDefaultControl (change)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
            {{post1}}
            per post
    </mat-radio-button>
          
    <br><br>
    <mat-radio-button formControlName="select1" value=story ngDefaultControl (change)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)"> 
              {{story}}
              per Story
    </mat-radio-button>
    <br><br>
            
    <mat-radio-button formControlName="select1" value=oth ngDefaultControl (change)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
             {{oth}}
              both
     </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

you can also pass the radio value as parameter in `onSearchChange` instead of `$event.target.value`